# how to keep alphabet loop separately by lowecase and uppercase in Caesar Cipher?

Tags: java, ascii, caesar-cipher

I am trying to challenge the Caesar Cipher problem, but am stuck at one condition, the question not only move n element position but also keep loop internally in the ASCII range, so 'z' will go to 'c' not '|' if n=3.
Could someone enlighten me how to get loop inside of Character.isLetter and Character.isLowerCase base on what I am doing now? hope I am on the track, and here is my code. Thank you

```
 public static String caesarCipher(String s, int k) {
    if(k>26){
        k = k % 26;
    }else if (k<26){
        k = (k % 26) + 26;
    }
    
    String result = new String();
    int length = s.length();
    
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(ch)){ // only for alphabet  
            if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)){ // for lower case a-z
                char cha = (char)(ch+k);
                if(cha > 'z'){
                    result += (char)(ch - (26 - k));
                } else {
                    result += cha;
                }
            } else if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){ // for upper case a-z
                char cha = (char)(ch+k);
                if(cha > 'Z'){
                    result += (char)(ch - (26 - k));
                }else {
                    result += cha;
                }
            }
        } else {
            result += ch;
        }
    }
    return result;
    }
```

Comment: Is it an option to define an array with all the valid characters and work on the array instead?

Comment: I think you've got too much code: For each char, 1) perform the shift using only lowercase (to lowercase). 2) If the original char is uppercase, make the result uppercase.